# Restart the order number count each day in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a flutter app and my client wants me to generate customer order numbers starting from 1 each day.

So, Day 1: order Number 1, 2, 3 ... etc
Day 2: order number 1, 2, 3 ... etc

How can I accomplish this in dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store the current date in a database-field "dateField" and the highest orderNumber of the day in another database-field "orderNumberLast".

Before adding a new order I would proof if "dateField" equals the current date.
If so, I would set orderNumberLast = orderNumberLast +1.
If not, I would set "dateField" to currentDate and orderNumberLast=1

Comment: makes sense. How will you compare the date field from DB to current date? Is current date derived from user's phone?

Comment: yes, current date derives from users phone, when doing client side. I don't know how to get date from server. if you use firebase you can use a cloud function with server-date when order is created.

Comment: The only issue with using a user's phone to get the date  in my opinion comes when a user decides to change their device's date and time. That's going to be an issue don't you think?

Comment: if the users aren't international it would be ok I think